# Using an asp.net webform ValidationSummary with bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am trying to do some styling on my page, and I really would like to implement the built -in modal that bootstrap has for displaying my ValidationSummary control, along with any other messages I may want. So far, I can get the modal to pop up, but the button never reaches my OnClick method, and it does not display the validation summary. I assume this has something to do with posting, and I was wondering if there is a way around this, and if I can still implement the modal?

My page looks something like this currently:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <script>
        //MODAL SCRIPT
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').focus()
        })
    </script>


...


<!-- PROGRAM NAME -->
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramName_Label" runat="server" Text="Program Name:" CssClass="label-program"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramName" runat="server" class="form-control text-fix"></asp:TextBox>
                    </p>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ProgramNameValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Program Name is required." ControlToValidate="ProgramName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

...

 <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitProgram" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitProgram_Click" 
                CssClass="listview-buttons"  Font-Underline="false" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal">Submit Program</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>

        <!-- BOOTSTRAP MODAL DIALOG -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="ValidationList" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to add this function on your page:

```
   function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
            if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: your code appending bootstrap modal popup after browser alert with validation summary.. Is there a way to control browser alert details with bootstrap modal popup?

Comment: what do you mean by browser alert?

Comment: if you have ShowMessageBox attribute set to true. Remove it or set it to false. @Pranesh

Comment: i meant browser alert as normal jquery alert(); type dialog box with a check box "prevent additional dialog box"...  I used your code in my project, where the browser alert dialog box appears first then your function code is called then bootstrap dialog box appearing. do you have any suggestion for this @Irfan TahirKheli. where is the setting "Showmessagebox"? so that i can try it with false state ?